# Azure API Management payload size

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there any limit on payload size in Azure API Management? I read that Max buffered payload size is 2MB for Consumption Tier. Is it the same for all other tiers as well?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the 2 MB limit is for Consumption tier. There is no payload size limit for other tiers as far as API Management is concerned. See [API Management limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#api-management-limits) for details. However, if you are parsing the payload within the APIM then there may be some limitations.

Also, for uploading large amounts of data then it is recommended to use the blob storage. There is some discussion on the topic on this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbf2ca4e-7d6a-4ff2-8e87-ddf813265612/azure-api-management-payload-size-issue?forum=azureapimgmt)

Comment: Note that this is "buffer" limit, i.e. if you decide to read whole request/response at APIM level. If you don't do that through policies, there is no limit.